# how to hide the seek bar of the ads in video.js player using vast plugin

Tags: video.js

I have a video.js player working with in-roll pre-roll ads before the actual video starts. but i am unable to get rid of seek bar in the ad 
I have used VAST pluging to get this thing working.the java script option passed to vast.js are below

[Ad video with Seek bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13J4n.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
ads: {
    'skipAd': {
    'enabled': true,
    'timeOut': 10,
     },


    'servers'  : [
    {
        'apiAddress': '../static/vast.xml'
        //'apiAddress' : 'http://some.domain/xdr-redirect/?http://some.domain/xml/vast.xml', //for xdr only
        //'xdrMethod': 'yql' //['yql' | 'xdr']
    }
    ], 
    'schedule' : [
        {
            'position' : 'pre-roll',
            'startTime': '00:00:00'
        },
    {
        'position' : 'mid-roll',
        'startTime': '00:00:07'
    },
    {
        'position' : 'post-roll'
    }
    ],

}
};
_V_("video", options);
```

is there an option that can be passed to vast.js or add some code to disable the seek bar.

thanx in advance for the answers.. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

VideoJS let you register event callback.
You can register a function to `vast.adStart` and `vast.adEnd` to set the bar display: none or block, whatever fit's your usecase.

```
player.on('vast.adStart', function () {
    document.querySelector('.vjs-progress-control').style.display = "none";
});
```